# Get "lowest" date of parents great grand child with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to learn LINQ - the hard way.
I have a few entities which all are connected in sequence
Department -> Groups -> Works -> project
project has a startdate (and an end date)

**I'm trying to get the startdate of the Group with the first startdate so to speak.**

I've tried:
`Department.Groups.Select(g => g.Works.Select(w => w.project.StartDate).Min())`

and various variations thereof. 
The problem being it returns a list in a list in a list, and I'm getting dizzy from just thinking about it :)

I've tried to work my way backwards from 
`g.Works.Select(w=> w.Project.StartDate).Min()` which gives me the lowest date for Works
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So would that make them the great grandchild?

Comment: don't you want to order by and then take the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten your List with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then apply `Min` like:

```
var minDate = Department.Groups
                 .SelectMany(g => g.Works.Select(w => w.project.StartDate))
                 .Min();
```

That will return the minimum date for all the `Works` under all `Groups`.

Comment: If i were to add yet ANOTHER child - I just had to SelectMany once more - correct? - Great, Fast Answer btw. will Accept once I can

Comment: @VisualBean, If adding another child would give you another nested list then use. Basically `SelectMany` will flatten the List, so in case of `List<List<DateTime>>` you will end up with `List<DateTime>`

Comment: @Habib: I'd ignore it. There was another guy here who had put the same exact answer as you, and got called out for it. It may be a "revenge" downvote.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, I don't think it is a revenge downvote, that answer was posted way after the downvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the date then Habib's flatten solution is good.  If you want the whole record you can order by and then take the first record, like this:

```
Department
  .Groups
  .OrderBy(g => g.Works.Select(w => w.project.StartDate))
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: `OrderBy` on a collection ? not really sure if that would work as intended.